# Set default range in ngx datepicker Quick select ranges

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

On setting the default range values in ngx datepicker, the Quick ranges are not marked as selected. I have set the date range of last 30 days in the `bsValue` variable and it is highlighting the dates in the calendar but the Quick range option for this range which is **Last 30 Days** is not marked as selected. I have seen the `selectedRange` property in `BsCustomDatesViewComponent` class but am not sure how to call this property. Any help will be highly appreciated.

This is how i am defining my Quick ranges

```
ranges: IDateRange[] = [{
    value: [new Date(moment().add(-30, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD")), new Date(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"))],
    label: 'Last 30 Days'
  }, {
    value: [new Date(moment([moment().year() - 2, 0, 1]).format("YYYY-MM-DD")), new Date(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"))],
    label: 'All Days'
  }];
```

Here i am setting the default range to `bsValue`

```
this.bsValue = [new Date(moment().add(-30, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD")),new Date(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"))];
```

Here i am calling the `bsDaterangepicker` in `input` tag

```
<input id="searchField" type="text" placeholder="Please select the date range"
                  class="form-control case-list-search" (bsValueChange)="dateRangeCreated($event)"
                  [bsConfig]="{ ranges: ranges, rangeInputFormat : 'MM/DD/YYYY', dateInputFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY', showWeekNumbers: false,  containerClass:'theme-blue' }"
                  bsDaterangepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue">
```

[image]

PS: I have tried to find the solution on google but didn't find anything helping. Thanks.